# div moves to top of the list on click and resizes

Tags: jquery, html, click

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="column">
            <div class="object">
                //some text and pictures
            </div>

            <div class="object">
               //some text and pictures
            </div>

            <div class="object">
               //some text and pictures
            </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to click any of these .object so it moves to the top of that list and gets bigger. Without dragging - just click.

I tried jquery append, swap and sortable but cannot figure out how to do that with divs (not ul) without dragging.

**SOLVED**
Thanks to Lynel.
Here is the working codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwPqQa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javaScript and make use of `insertBefore` to accomplish your goals.

```js
function clicked( element ){
    var column = document.getElementById( 'column' );
    var node = element;
    column.insertBefore( element, column.childNodes[ 0 ] );
}
```

```html
<div id="column">
    <div class="object" onclick="clicked( this )">
        some text and pictures 1
    </div>
    
    <div class="object" onclick="clicked( this )">
        some text and pictures 2
    </div>
    
    <div class="object" onclick="clicked( this )">
        some text and pictures 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am grateful for your effort but once I click a div, the style disapears. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwPqQa

Comment: Damn! Works great! Is there any option to add animation or do I have to use a special library?

Comment: I'm glad it works for you! You can add animation to this if you'd like but what exactly do you want to do? PS. Please accept my answer so others can find it more easily by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: Done! I'd like this clicked div to move (animate) to the top and grow (just the height) while other divs go down.
I'm building website for myself that contains list of restaurants etc. Above that list there is google maps. So the user scrolls through the list, clicks an object which goes to the top of the list and grows to reveal more detailed description of a particular restaurant.

Comment: You don't have enough rep to enter a chat room, otherwise, i'd invite you. If you can't solve the animation aspect on your own, ask a new question and we will try to help you :)

Comment: OK, hold on a second.

Comment: Damn, as a new user I have to wait 50 more minutes before posting next question. Can you wait? Here's my email: peter(d0t)gray(at)o2(d0t)pl

Comment: What you want to do is sort of advanced. You can easily make the div expand after it is clicked with CSS, but the hard part is animating it to the top, and then expanding. My advice would be to read up on some of these tutorials here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp, but your best route might be to use jquery animation. Study that as well. Good luck! If I'm not around someone else will jump in!

Comment: You're great. I really appreciate your help. Good luck to you too!

Answer (score 0):

To insert the 2nd element at the top of the list from the list use:

```
var el = $(".column div:nth-child(1)");

$(".column").prepend(el);

el.remove();
```

To insert the 2nd element at the bottom of the list from the list use:

```
var el = $(".column div:nth-child(1)");

$(".column").append(el);

el.remove();
```